# Xamarin.Forms iOS flipping from portrait to landscape not working (iPhone only)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have problem with resizing Grid on iPhone.
I subscribed event SizeChanged, which is rising when I'm rotating device. 
Here are methods which I'm using to change grid size:

```
private void MainMenu_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Width > Height)
        {
            ImageSunLogo.Margin = 0;
            GridMenuItems = ChangeGridOrientation(GridMenuItems, 2, 3);

        }
        if (Height > Width)
        {
            ImageSunLogo.Margin = 20;
            GridMenuItems = ChangeGridOrientation(GridMenuItems, 3, 2);
        }
    }

    private Grid ChangeGridOrientation(Grid gridParent, int nOfRows, int nOfColumns)
    {
        var resultGrid = gridParent;
        var parentChilds = gridParent.Children.ToList();

        ClearGridRowsColsChilds(ref resultGrid);

        for (int i = 0; i < nOfRows; i++)
        {
            resultGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nOfColumns; i++)
        {
            resultGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

        int currentChildIndex = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < nOfRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < nOfColumns; col++)
            {
                resultGrid.Children.Add(parentChilds[currentChildIndex], col, row);
                currentChildIndex++;
            }

        }

        return resultGrid;
    }

    private void ClearGridRowsColsChilds(ref Grid grid)
    {
        GridMenuItems.Children.Clear();
        GridMenuItems.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        GridMenuItems.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    }
```

This code working perfectly on Android devices, iPad, but on iPhone while changing orientation from portrait to landscape by rotate phone to the left side (to the right working normally), app don't rising this event, and grid does not flip. 
Have anyone experienced something like that?

Comment: Did you check the Landspace Left in info.plist?And what is the version of your iPhone?

Comment: Ok...it was that obvious. Thank you.

Comment: I will post it as answer,can you accept it?

Comment: Ok, I'will mark it.

Comment: Now you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `landscape` .Do not forget to check the `Device Orientation` in `info.plist`

[image]